# Return the total amount of calculated items in a list

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with Quantity and Price

In the form, beyond these fields, I have the Total = [Quantity] * [Price]

Moreover, the main form I have SomaTotal = Sum([Total])

Ie, the classical sum price that everyone can do.

question:

How do I put this in a full list of Sales?

Ie I have this total for each sale, but I needed a list to return me all sales, and the total of each.

I would have to do a nested query?

The picture is illustrative. I need this list in MS Access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
SELECT
    SUM (SalesSales) AS E1
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    (Customer = 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    SUM (SalesSales) AS E1
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    (Customer = 2)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    SUM (SalesSales) AS E1
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    (Customer = 3)
```

Comment: I resolve using: SELECT detVendas.id, Sum([Quant]*[Preco]) AS Total
FROM detVendas
GROUP BY detVendas.id;
Thanks.